# Serializing and deserializing json formatted objects

Tags: asp.net, json, facebook

Could anyone suggest a few tutorial for seraialization and deserialization.. Basically I am getting this data from data from Facebook

```
string json = this.WebRequest(oAuthFacebook.Method.GET, url, String.Empty);

UserInfo ui = js.Deserialize<UserInfo>(json);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb = sb.Append("Name : " + ui.name + "<br/>");
sb = sb.Append("<Img src='" + ui.picture + "' alt='' />");
sb = sb.Append("Bio : " + ui.bio + "<br/>");
sb = sb.Append("Quotes : " + ui.quotes + "<br/>");
```

here is it deserializing.. Before it is displayed on the web browser, I need to save the user info, events, mailbox in a database and then display it on the web browser

Thanks for reading
SC

Comment: You might find people more willing to help you if you accept some of the answers you've been given.  And what does saving to a database have to do with serializing and deserializing?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest using the NewtonSoft.Json library for both serializing and deserializing. Very easy to use, very consistently good feedback. You can either find it at Codeplex or through NuGet/Package Manager in Visual Studio.

Edit - only answering the main question - saving to database etc is completely unrelated. Try and keep each question separate, so that other people searching for answers will find relevant content. As it is, someone trying to do your database stuff would never find your question/answers.